# Command not found

Tags: macos, terminal

I am quite new to the Mac Terminal environment.
I donwloaded sqlplus (which is recognised as a UNIX executable program) and then in Terminal I do cd  a few times until I arrive in the folder I put this in (\Applications\instantclient_10) in this case.
When I type 'ls' I see a listing of all the files including the sqlplus.  So I would then expect to simply type at the Telnet prompt 'sqlplus' and then this would start but instead keep getting

> -bash: sqlplus: command not found

This is problem one.

I have now downloaded MySQL and again, when I go to the correct folder (\Library\StarupItems\MySQLCOM) and I type 'ls' I see my files (including MySQLCOM) but when I come to try to 'run' this by simply typing 'MySQLCOM' again the message is:

> -base: MySQLCOM: command not found

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run binary/executables in current folder you need to prefix them with ./

```
./sqlplus
```

The idea here is that you want to force execution of local file and not run it accidentally. Imagine app that would put `ls` binary into it's folder and it would automatically run if did `ls` in that folder.

Comment: Fantastic - that did the job - where can I find out more about this?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html not sure if it's too much.