# Restart Genymotion emulator with adb: command not found

Tags: android, macos, adb, genymotion

I've installed [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and I want to restart it with `adb reboot`. However when I try.. well, just look:

```
MacBook-Pro:tools Dean$ pwd
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools
MacBook-Pro:tools Dean$ ls -la
total 9672
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 Dean  admin      170 Jun 13 11:36 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 9 Dean  admin      306 Jun 13 11:36 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 Dean  admin  1595024 Jun 13 11:36 aapt
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 Dean  admin  2804800 Jun 13 11:36 adb
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 Dean  admin   544896 Jun 13 11:36 glewinfo
MacBook-Pro:tools Dean$ adb reboot
-bash: adb: command not found
```

Anyone know why this would happen? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555578/command-not-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly adb binary is not in your PATH. **The PATH environment variable is a colon-delimited list of directories that your shell searches through when you enter a command.** Bash looks for adb in PATH not your current directory.  So try below command

```
./adb reboot
```